# Replacing special character "." with "-" in dataframe column name in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

I want to replace `"BMU 1 Cell 1 Temp. (C)"` with `"BMU_1_Cell_1_Temp_C"` as well type cast the column to double.

Tried the following options:

1. Provided the column name in single quotes

```
val df= df1.withColumn("`BMU 1 Cell 1 Temp. (C)`",col("`BMU 1 Cell 1 Temp. (C)`").cast("Double")).withColumnRenamed("`BMU 1 Cell 1 Temp. (C)`","BMU_1_Cell_1_Temp_C")
```

2. 

```
val df= df1.withColumn("BMU 1 Cell 1 Temp. (C)",col("BMU 1 Cell 1 Temp. (C)").cast("Double")).withColumnRenamed("BMU 1 Cell 1 Temp. (C)","BMU_1_Cell_1_Temp_C").replaceAll("\\.","_"))
```

Getting the below error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`BMU 1 PCB Temp. (C)`'
```

Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my spark 3.0.0. test.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("1", "123.456"))).toDF("id", "BMU 1 Cell 1 Temp. (C)")

df.withColumnRenamed("BMU 1 Cell 1 Temp. (C)", "BMU_1_Cell_1_Temp_C")
  .withColumn("BMU_1_Cell_1_Temp_C", $"BMU_1_Cell_1_Temp_C".cast("double")).show

+---+-------------------+
| id|BMU_1_Cell_1_Temp_C|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|            123.456|
+---+-------------------+
```

---

Either this one works.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("1", "123.456"))).toDF("id", "BMU 1 Cell 1 Temp. (C)")

val cols = df.columns.map(c => c.replaceAll("([.] )|[ ]", "_").replaceAll("[()]", ""))

df.toDF(cols: _*).withColumn("BMU_1_Cell_1_Temp_C", $"BMU_1_Cell_1_Temp_C".cast("double")).show()

+---+-------------------+
| id|BMU_1_Cell_1_Temp_C|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|            123.456|
+---+-------------------+
```